# custom formatting of individual Spinner items not working

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to have a particular text appearance on the first item displayed in a `Spinner`.
Although the code below is called and executed, the first item in the spinner is not formatted as expected.

```
public class ClubsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private static List<String> mClubs = null;
public TextView tv;

public ClubsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> dataset) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, dataset);
    mClubs = dataset;

    ListIterator<String> listIterator = mClubs.listIterator();
    String s = listIterator.next();
    listIterator.set(s.substring(1));
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.club, null);
    }
    
    tv = v.findViewById(R.id.club);

    String club = mClubs.get(position);
    if (club != null) {
        if (position == 0) {
            tv.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                tv.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
            } else {
                tv.setTextAppearance(mContext, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
            }
        } else {
            tv.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                tv.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            } else {
                tv.setTextAppearance(mContext, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            }
        }

        tv.setText(club);
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/club"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />
```

And this is how I use this adapter:

```
        Spinner clubSpinner = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.clubSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> clubsAdapter = new ClubsAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.club, clubNames);
        clubsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        clubSpinner.setAdapter(clubsAdapter);
```

*** EDIT ***
This is the XML for the Spinner, as requested:

```
    <Spinner            android:id="@+id/clubSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/courseSpinner"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

Comment: Could you please post the spinner XML also? I need the whole code to help you. Or more important, that part, where the issue appears.

Comment: Spinner XML added, as requested. The issue is the following: when I use the debugger, I see that the "settypeface" and "settextappearance" in the "getview" method are executed, but without affecting the result displayed. It looks like some other method later overrides/rollbacks them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `setTypeface` **after** `setTextAppearance`. The latter also sets the type face.
Simple and stupid...

The correct code is

```
    if (position == 0) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            tv.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
        } else {
            tv.setTextAppearance(mContext, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
        }
        tv.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC));
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            tv.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
        } else {
            tv.setTextAppearance(mContext, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
        }
        tv.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
    }
```